# "Requiring Wifi permissions limits app availability on TVs that support only Ethernet" warning in Android Studio - can anything be done about this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, ethernet, android-tv

I'm developing an Android app (a game) that supports phones and TVs too, and can play multiplayer via LAN (WiFi or Ethernet) or WiFi Direct.

Android Studio warns me with a Lint warning in the manifest that says that if I *"require Wifi permissions"*, then it will *"limit the app availability on TVs that support only Ethernet"* (TVs that don't have Wifi).

[image: Android Studio warning screenshot]

I would like to support TVs without Wifi too. The multiplayer code is written in a way that it handles the Ethernet-only situation.

However, the Wifi-related permissions are normal permissions, and their declarations can't be removed from the manifest.

Is there anything that can be done here to keep my app available for these TVs without Wifi?

Comment: Have you added [a `<uses-feature>` element to say that WiFi is not required](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element?hl=en#permissions)?

Comment: @CommonsWare - no, I haven't tried that - having read the linked page, it seems like adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />` is what's needed. I've just tested and it resolves the warning. Thank you, this is the solution. Feel free to post it as such and I'll accept!

Comment: It's interesting that there are similar warnings that I've just noticed for `BLUETOOTH` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission declarations, and they provide an automatic fix action where Android Studio adds the `uses-feature` with `android:required="false"` for bluetooth and gps, respectively. But there is no automatic action for the warning about this TV-Ethernet thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some permissions, when you request them, cause Android to [think that you need the associated hardware](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element?hl=en#permissions). In your case, requesting `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` cause Android to think that you need WiFi hardware.

Adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />` downgrades that from "must have WiFi" to "can use WiFi". Beyond clearing up the Lint complaint, it will help with actual app distribution, allowing your app to run on hardware that has only Ethernet. In addition to some TV platforms, there may be some Chromeboxes that also are Ethernet-only.

> But there is no automatic action for the warning about this TV-Ethernet thing

I do not see a bug report for that in [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=%22android.hardware.wifi%22). If you are in position to create a throwaway project that has your `<uses-permission>` elements, you might consider filing a feature request to get the quick-fix that you seek added to Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed answer! I was aware of the possibility of implicit uses-feature declarations (seen it with CAMERA and autofocus), but not about the place in the documentation where the full list of these is collected, so this is very useful. About raising the issue, I will look into it tomorrow and will likely raise it.